# NoSQL (mongoDB) or Relational Database

Tags: database, nosql

I'm building a node.js application and I do not really know if NoSQL database like MongoDB could be used for my needs.

Basically, I have 2 models. If I think in term of relational database, this is how I would set up things:

1. FirstModel which only has a couple of attributes and a 1 to many relationship to SecondModel.
2. SecondModel containing a foreign key toward FirstModel.

An item of FirstModel will have a lot of corresponding item of SecondModel.

Any idea if NoSQL is a good candidate for this ?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB surely can handle this kind of models. But the decision about MongoDB vs RDBMS depends more on the *queries* you need: MongoDB doesn't support `JOIN`s!
If that's ok for your problem or can be covered by a bit of denormalization, then MongoDB is ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

To make a proper decision, we would need to know your access patterns for the data. MongoDB is a pretty flexible default if you want to try NoSQL. Likely in this case SecondModel would be embedded in FirstModel- FirstModel would contain an array of SecomdModel. This gives you the power of joins at the cost of being a little [harder to use](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29).

Comment: Let's say that for each record of FirstModel there are 1000 records of secondmodel pointing toward it. Would that be a problem as secondmodel is embedded in firsmodel ? I would need to access one record of the firstmodel from a record from the secondmodel. No join table involved in this, would this be fine ?